# Is this slowloris attack or not?

Tags: apache

IP is hidden in apache log for privacy, except last octet.
/billing is our application start page. But it doesn't make sense that it sends POST requests, and get 500 response.

Or maybe this is legitimate old IE 7 browser who can't handle  our site, ant sets into loop?

There is about 20000 such requests

```
xx.xx.xx.223 - - [30/May/2014:13:40:54 +0200] "POST /billing HTTP/1.1" 500 613 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.503l3; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; MSOffice 12)"
xx.xx.xx.223 - - [30/May/2014:13:40:54 +0200] "POST /billing HTTP/1.1" 500 613 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.503l3; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; MSOffice 12)"
xx.xx.xx.223 - - [30/May/2014:13:40:54 +0200] "POST /billing HTTP/1.1" 500 613 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.503l3; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; MSOffice 12)"
xx.xx.xx.223 - - [30/May/2014:13:40:54 +0200] "POST /billing HTTP/1.1" 500 613 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.503l3; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; MSOffice 12)"
xx.xx.xx.223 - - [30/May/2014:13:40:55 +0200] "POST /billing HTTP/1.1" 500 613 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.503l3; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; MSOffice 12)"
xx.xx.xx.223 - - [30/May/2014:13:40:55 +0200] "POST /billing HTTP/1.1" 500 613 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.503l3; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; MSOffice 12)"
xx.xx.xx.223 - - [30/May/2014:13:40:56 +0200] "POST /billing HTTP/1.1" 500 613 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.503l3; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; MSOffice 12)"
xx.xx.xx.223 - - [30/May/2014:13:40:56 +0200] "POST /billing HTTP/1.1" 500 613 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.503l3; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; MSOffice 12)"
xx.xx.xx.223 - - [30/May/2014:13:40:56 +0200] "POST /billing HTTP/1.1" 500 613 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.503l3; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; MSOffice 12)"
xx.xx.xx.223 - - [30/May/2014:13:40:56 +0200] "POST /billing HTTP/1.1" 500 613 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.503l3; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; MSOffice 12)"
xx.xx.xx.223 - - [30/May/2014:13:40:58 +0200] "POST /billing HTTP/1.1" 500 613 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.503l3; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; MSOffice 12)"
xx.xx.xx.223 - - [30/May/2014:13:40:58 +0200] "POST /billing HTTP/1.1" 500 613 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.503l3; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; MSOffice 12)"
xx.xx.xx.223 - - [30/May/2014:13:40:58 +0200] "POST /billing HTTP/1.1" 500 613 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.503l3; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; MSOffice 12)"
xx.xx.xx.223 - - [30/May/2014:13:40:59 +0200] "POST /billing HTTP/1.1" 500 613 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.503l3; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; MSOffice 12)"
```

Comment: Without knowing more, I wouldn't say it's `Slowloris` in particular, or even an attack at all. At most it's an unsophisticated attack as the requests come too far apart to warrant that thought. However, having 20,000 of the same request appear in your log is alarming and itself and may be something you'd want to investigate further.

Comment: If I google "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.503l3; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; MSOffice 12)" it gives results only about slowloris, because it's default line in slowloris. But it can be legitimate request, right?

Comment: Please don't cross-post here and on SF!

Comment: to better detect a slowloris attack you could be interested in this answer on the the same topic : http://serverfault.com/a/445391/121727

Answer (score 1):

Your Apache log format does not include any information about the time it took to process each HTTP request, therefore we can neither confirm nor reject with 100% certainty the possibility of a Slowloris attack, since this attack achieves connection pool exhaustion by initiating a large number of connections and keeping them open for prolonged periods of time.

> There is about 20000 such requests

This information is irrelevant unless you specify the time-frame during which these requests were made.

It's hard to determine from your log snippet whether this is an actual attack or not. One would need historical data in order to determine the normal usage patterns of your application before being able to make such conclusions.

The "MS Office 12" part of the user-agent string would indicate that these requests originated from an application that is part of the Microsoft Office suite -unless of course the user-agent string is spoofed by some custom bot/crawler.

Comment: Office 12 is included with MS Outlook 2007 requests. Unless the full POST data is not logged (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/989967/best-way-to-log-post-data-in-apache), it is difficult to classify the logs as Slowloris attack.

Comment: @void_in Slowloris can be performed with legitimate POST requests, so full POST data is not always required to classify an attack as such. Request processing time on the other hand (%D or %T argument in Apache log format) can always be used to detect Slowloris with certainty.